# How many subgroups there is for $\mathbb{Z}_{23}\times \mathbb{Z}_{31}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, normal-subgroups

How many subgroups there is for $\mathbb{Z}_{23}\times \mathbb{Z}_{31}$?
I try to understand how to solve it but I don't finding a way...

I'll be glad if you help me with this...

Thank you!

Comment: you tried for small groups? some thing like "how many subgroups are there for $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{4}$"

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, I didn't know how to do this....

Answer (score 4):

Since I didn't see it in the other answers I shall remark the following: we certainly have that 
$$\;C_{23}\times C_{31}\cong C_{23\cdot 31}=C_{713}\;$$

... **and this group is cyclic**.  Thus, for any divisor of $\;713\;$ there is *one single, unique* subgroup of order that divisor, and since the only divisors of $\;713\;$ are $\;1\,,\,23\,,\,31\,,\,713\;$ (since $\;23\,,\,31\;$ are primes!), this group has only four subgroups, of which only two are non-trivial proper: $\;C_{23}\times\{1_{31}\}\;,\;\;\{1_{23}\}\times C_{31}\;$ , of order $\;23\,,\,\,31\;$ , resp.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. Then, by the Chinese remainder theorem,
$G=\mathbb{Z}/p\times \mathbb{Z}/q \simeq \mathbb{Z}/pq$, and by Lagrange the order of a subgroup is $1,p,q$ or $pq$. It is easy to see that we have exactly the four subgroups $0\times \mathbb{Z}/q$, $\mathbb{Z}/p\times 0$, the whole group and the trivial group. Now let $(p,q)=(23,31)$.

Comment: What are the four groups?
1. $0\times \mathbb{Z}/q$.
2. $\mathbb{Z}/p \times 0$.
3. the whole group...
4.????

Comment: 4. The trivial group: $0\times 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=\mathbb Z_{23}\times \mathbb Z_{31}$. Then $|G|=23\times 31$ and since $23$ and $31$ are prime, the only possible orders of a nontrivial proper subgroup of $G$ are $23$ and $31$. But then we can easily verify that  $\mathbb Z_{23}\times \{0\}$ is the only subgroup of $G$ of order $23$ and $\{0\}\times\mathbb Z_{31}$ is the only subgroup of $G$ of order $31$. Hence the only nontrivial subgroups of $G$ are $\mathbb Z_{23}\times \{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times\mathbb Z_{31}$.